# Get most duplicated entries

Tags: mysql

I'm looking to get the most duplicated entries for an ID.

Here's my table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS rating (
    ip varchar(255), 
    id bigint(32), 
    likes BOOL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (ip, id)
);
```

So an IP can rate as many ids as they want. I'm trying to get the most duplicating entries:

```
SELECT * FROM rating WHERE likes = TRUE;
```

This returns all liked ids, But what I'm looking for is to get the most liked ids (Top 10 of them).

Comment: `group by`, `count()`, and `order by count() desc`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty straightforward:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS popularity, id
  FROM rating
  GROUP BY id
  ORDER BY popularity DESC
  LIMIT 10
```

Comment: I've tried using `WHERE likes = TRUE`, but I'm looking to get most liked ones (likes - dislikes), Currently an ID with 2 likes and 4 dislikes is still on top list.

Comment: If you need to compute the difference you'll need to create a derivative table that has net scores. You can automatically update this in your application code as part of your voting procedure, or you can add a `TRIGGER` to do it for you.